# unexplained sus4 progress in bach's choral

Tags: chord-progressions, analysis, nonchord-tones

[image: Bach choral #5, m. 2]

> **score is measure 2 in Bach 371 Chorales No.5 'An Wasserflüssen Babylon' in G major**

i think beat 2 is v7sus4 but if G in DDGC is suspension note,
G in previous chord(AEGB) is must be  Harmonic Tone in that chord.

but if G in AEGB is 7th note of ii7, that 7th note not prepared in previous chord(ACEC)

and if that AEGB is not ii7 but the vi, non chord tone A in the bass is not resolve the next chord (A going to D)

and i considered A as a pedal tone but too short to be a pedal tone.

and, actually this choral is common time, and that suspension G in V7sus4 is come out to weak beat. As far as I know, suspension notes come from strong beats.
So that is also confusing. please if you can help this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beat one — both halves — is ii7. The soprano B between beats 1 and 2 is a non-harmonic tone, lower neighbor to the C.

Comment: maybe i marked it wrong? i mean i ask v7sus4(DDGC) , that's call beat 3?

Comment: you mean DDGC is ii7 too? so 'DD' is Anticipation?

Comment: @guss2222 My mistake. Fixed now.

Comment: ok. but actually that's not clear G in ii7 is not prepared in previous chord(ACEC)

Comment: @guss2222 The entire beat is considered ii7. The mistake you're making is trying to analyze every single note as part of a chord. Also, the seventh can be entered by lead, it just has to resolve by step.

Comment: sorry but i don't understand that 'the seventh can be entered by lead,'

Comment: @guss2222 "by leap". Typo.

Comment: it can? i don't know that.. so you mean DDGC is ii7 right? if not  analyze every single note as part of a chord as you said but that's still weird part

Comment: "Classical" music analysis considers the melody to be its own entity and not necessarily part of the chord progression (which itself may not even be considered to exist.) The idea of trying to write the melody as the top note of each chord comes from popular music or jazz (and I think complicates things greatly.) A common pattern is having a chord (quarter note) with a 32nd note melody above it; the composer didn't think of 8 notes per beat. A bass run under a chord isn't well-analyzed as a bunch of chords. Pedal points and wedge progressions don't either.

Comment: @ttw Aaron says beat 1 is ii7, and im not sure he talking DDGC in beat2 is ii7 too. and i don't know about  wedge progressions.

Comment: @guss2222 DDGC is V7, but the G is a suspension. The G is prepared in the ii7 chord in beat 1.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Another way to look at it, less harmonically, more melodically, which gets more to your point about an apparent *unprepared dissonance*, is `F#` in beats 4 and 2 are chord tones of dominant chords (circled green), and the `E` and `G` are a *changing tones* motion (boxed in red.)

If you sing that part out loud while playing it, I think the changing tones aspect is pretty clear.

The `G` doesn't immediately return to `F#`, so the changing tones sort of morph into a suspension.

Dissonances are prepared only as a matter of old counterpoint convention, with sometimes a rationalization that prepared dissonances are easier to sing. To the extent that we might look for an "easier to sing" explanation of the `G` - a dissonant seventh above bass `A` and dissonant fourth about bass `D` - the changing tones pattern is certainly an "easy" way to navigate from a consonant tone, through a dissonance, back to a consonance.

Comment: It seems reasonable, but I think the line can come out the same as the changing tone at any time. In addition, one of the claimed changing tones even becomes a harmonic sound. (E in ACEC) So, in my opinion, this is a rather subjective analysis.

Comment: @guss2222 Most analysis is subjective.

Comment: It's definitely not a textbook changing tones example. But I thought it worth pointing out it follows a really common _linear_ pattern to move through a dissonance.

Comment: With such common focus on chordal analysis, it's easy to forget the linear aspect of Bach's compositions.

Comment: That's a Good point and worth remembering. but, as long as it does not function as a changing tone, there is no need to call it a changing tone. I think it can be expressed to the extent that the movement of the voice is the same as the change tone.